# C# email alert not picking up new code

Tags: c#, sql, email

I have following code for sending an email alert to around 60 users when an extract gets uploaded.  However something strange is happening, it is sending to the previous query results not the new ones.  The only difference is the quantity of users before it was sending to only a few people now its sending to a larger quantity.  But on the code with larger quantity the application seems to not see that it has changed and sends to previous users.  Like its cached the query or something.  I don't know whats going on.  But when I do change it to just one email address it works fine and picks up changes.

```
  if (Session["ExtractNo"].ToString() == "Extract 1")
            {
                //Connection String (SendEmail)
                string SendEmail = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SendEmail"].ConnectionString;

                SqlDataReader reader;
                String SendMessage = "SELECT Name, Position, Email FROM AuthorisedStaff Where Position = 'CM' or Position = 'DHOD' or Position = 'HOD'"; //<---- change position before launch

                using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(SendEmail))
                {
                    myConnection.Open();
                    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(SendMessage, myConnection);

                    ArrayList emailArray = new ArrayList();
                    reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

                    var emails = new List<EmailCode>();

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        emails.Add(new EmailCode
                        {
                            Email = Convert.ToString(reader["Email"]),
                            Name = Convert.ToString(reader["Name"]),
                            Position = Convert.ToString(reader["Position"])
                        });
                    }

                    foreach (EmailCode email in emails)
                    {
                        //Email Config

                        const string username = "roll@test.co.uk"; //account address
                        const string password = "######"; //account password

                        SmtpClient smtpclient = new SmtpClient();
                        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                        MailAddress fromaddress = new MailAddress("roll@test.co.uk", "PTLP"); //address and from name

                        smtpclient.Host = "omavex11";  //host name for particular email address
                        smtpclient.Port = 25; //port number for particular email address

                        mail.From = fromaddress;
                        mail.To.Add(email.Email);
                        mail.Subject = ("PTLP Check");

                        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

                        //change context of message below as appropriate
                        mail.Body = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(email.Name) + " <br /> <p>Part Time Lecturer Payroll details are now available for checking.  If any changes need made please notify MIS as soon as possible. </p> <p>Please ensure all Adjustments have also been submitted.  All Adjustments not submitted on time will be paid the following month. </p>    ";


                        //smtpclient.EnableSsl = true;
                        smtpclient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                        smtpclient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password);

                        smtpclient.Send(mail);

                    }
                }

            }
```

Comment: Step through the  code using a debugger. I suspect the SQL String `SendMessage = "SELECT Name, Position, Email FROM AuthorisedStaff Where Position = 'CM' or Position = 'DHOD' or Position = 'HOD'"` doesn't change.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bulk emails will not send, c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39290257/bulk-emails-will-not-send-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the list first before adding new items/objects
I assume that this

```
var emails = new List<EmailCode>();
```

is the list.

Comment: `var emails = "" or EmailCode = ""`

Comment: `var emails = " " `

Comment: I am getting this error:- **A local variable named 'emails cannot be declared on this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'emails', which is arleady used in a parent or current scope to denote something else.

Comment: Do this `var emails = " "` before `var emails = new List<EmailCode>();`. All in all your code will be : `var emails = " " `; `emails=new List<EmailCode>();`

Comment: Thats what i did do

Comment: All in all your code will be: `var emails = " " ; emails=new List<EmailCode>();`

Comment: Says cannot implicitly convert type generic.list to string

Comment: `var emails = new List<EmailCode>();
            emails.Clear();`